# Symfony + wordpress

Tags: wordpress, symfony2

Estoy realizando un symfony que tendrá un subapartado de wordpress. 
El caso es que tengo la instalación de wordpress bajo la carpeta web/wordpress.

He seguido el siguiente manual:
http://gorkamu.com/2014/05/como-usar-wordpress-junto-symfony/

Pero no sé qué tengo que poner en el routing para que esa carpeta funcione como un wordpress independiente, he intentado con:

```
wordpress:
    path: web/wordpress
    defaults: 
        _file: web/wordpress/index.php


wordpress:
    path: wordpress
    defaults: 
        _file: wordpress/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo tengo funcionando en varias páginas web y lo más sencillo es hacerlo directamente en la configuración de Apache, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  midominio.com
  ServerAlias www.midominio.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/midominio.com/current/web

  <Directory "/var/www/midominio.com/current/web">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

 Alias /blog /var/www/blog.midominio.com/

 <Directory "/var/www/blog.midominio.com">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  LogLevel notice
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/midominio.com_ssl.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog  "/var/log/httpd/midominio.com_ssl.error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Con esto, quien se encarga de todo es Apache y así no tienes que hacer modificaciones en Symfony de ningún tipo.

Del mismo modo, Wordpress y Symfony están en directorios separados y te ahorras posibles colisiones.

Comment: Esto que dices tiene todo el sentido del mundo. Pero en este caso lo que pretendo es coger los datos del Wordpress como endpoint. Y securizar el wordpress a través de routing de Symfony. Es una "paja mental" que tengo de intentar tener el wordpress bajo el Symfony y mostrar los datos del Wordpress dentro del Symfony como si fueran propios y que el Wordpress solo sea accesible a través del mismo dominio. Sé que puede no tener mucho sentido esto que explico, pero ya se ha convertido en un reto..

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez yo tuve que realizar una tarea similar. Para solucionarlo utilice este [Bundle](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle)

La forma de utilizar esta bien detallado en la [documentación](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle/blob/master/README.md)

Es un poco extenso pero me funciono.

También existe este otro Bundle que no lo probé pero puede funcionar:
https://github.com/outlandishideas/symfony-wordpress-edition

Saludos